# linux route specific machine traffic throw specific output interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routes, iptables

I have a linux machine Iam using as a router with multible interfaces and multible internet connection
say eth0--isp1

```
eth1--isp2

eth2--isp3
```

the gateway is eth0 throw isp1

and eth3--local1 10.0.0.x

```
eth4--local2 192.168.1.x
```

i need local1 ip 192.168.1.10 to go throw isp3, eth2

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use policy routing for this. You create a new routing table and use it when the source IP is 192.168.1.10.

```
ip route add ... table $TABLENUM                  # your usual routes, for the new table
...
ip route add default via $ISP3 table $TABLENUM    # gateway for the new table
ip rule add from 192.168.1.10/32 lookup $TABLENUM # use the new table for this IP
ip rule add to 192.168.1.10/32 lookup $TABLENUM   # make it symmetric, for clarity
```

Comment: that is true but you first need to create table by editing the file


/etc/iproute2/rt_tables

Answer (score 0):

Try `route add 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth4--local`, on the assumption these are locally-connected networks.  If not, you will need to specify a gateway machine to route the packets through also.  Truthfully your question is malformed (and probably belongs on serverfault).  If you already have addresses on those networks, these routes should already exist.  If you do not, your problem is likely more complicated than you think it is.